# Fix Nexus metadata download timeout

Tags: maven, nexus

I have setup a Nexus (version 2.11.2-06) with a Public group containing several repositories (hosted and proxies). It contains a proxy for the Central repository.

Currently Maven builds have problems while downloading the `maven-metadata.xml` for `com.google.guava.guava` through the public repository. The URL `.../nexus/content/groups/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml` does not respond while `.../nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml` responds quickly.

I do not see anything about this in the Nexus log file.

Any ideas how to fix it? I rebuild the Metadata, expired the cache and updated the index of the Public group. But it did not help.

When I look in the `storage/public` folder of the Nexus installation there is no folder for `com/google/guava`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I restarted the Nexus service and then it worked.